# postsperpage value not being applied

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I have a custom post type called `laptop`, and in my theme's `front-page.php` I have:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'laptop', 'postsperpage' => '30' ) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <!-- display laptops -->
```

However, only 10 laptops are displayed.

I find that in `Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most` was set to `10`, and changing this number changes the number of laptops displayed on the front page.

Am I wrong in thinking `postsperpage` should override `Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most`?

Comment: Why do people punish a question asker with down votes if they don't have the correct knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) it's not `postsperpage` but `posts_per_page`.